# How to adjust gif image to zpl/epl printer

Tags: image, printing, gif, zpl, epl

UPS webservice returns gif image instead of epl/zpl file, when I specify 'cash on delivery' option. So now I have a problem, how to adjust this gif image programatically, so it can be printed on zebra printer. 
This is the image I get:
[image]

Unfortunatelly I don't have zebra printer to test my tries, but I found out I can see print preview in Zebra Designer, so here's a preview of this image on printer (after rotation):
[image]

My question is how can I adjust this image programatically (or otherwise) so it can be correctly printed on zebra printer

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert the image to a format compatible with ZPL and upload that image to the printer through your ZPL.  You need to make sure your printer has enough memory to hold the image.

We use this method in our RocketShipIt Print Server for your exact need.  UPS COD labels don't currently support ZPL and we needed a workaround for our customers.

https://docs.rocketship.it/php/1-0/thermal-printing.html#sending-gif-jpeg-png-images-to-thermal-printer

Specifically we use the ^GW EPL2 command:

https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/gw_command.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I already found solution. I created html page with image in center (in div) and manipulated it's size with css. Then I converted html page to pdf with some third-party software. Now pdf document like that printed on zebra printer have a lot better quality then before, and the barcode can be read without problem.

Comment: @Dess Do you have the code you used to accomplish this? I am having a similar issue.